# My kernel's FLOP efficiency is very low

Tags: performance, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I implemented a kernel for pressure gradients computations. Based on used algorithm and previous parts which I did, the `ngb_list[]` is random and I do not have coalesced memory access. However, the double precision FLOP efficiency of the kernel is 0.2% of the peak performance on TESLA K40. It seems very low ...!

Also:

Global Memory Load Efficiency:      45.05%
Global Memory Store Efficiency:     100.00%

Is there a way to improve the DP FLOP efficiency and Global Memory Load Efficiency?

Here you can find the code:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

    typedef double  Float;

__global__ void pGrad_calculator(Float* pressure, Float* pressure_list,
                                 Float* interactionVectors_x, Float* interactionVectors_y, Float* interactionVectors_z,
                                 int* ngb_offset, int* ngb_size, int* ngb_list,
                                 Float* pressureGrad_x, Float* pressureGrad_y, Float* pressureGrad_z,
                                 int num){

    unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (idx < num){

        for (int j = ngb_offset[idx]; j < (ngb_offset[idx] + ngb_size[idx]); j++){
            Float pij = (pressure[idx] + pressure[ngb_list[j]]);
            pressureGrad_x[idx] += interactionVectors_x[j] * pij; 
            pressureGrad_y[idx] += interactionVectors_y[j] * pij;
            pressureGrad_z[idx] += interactionVectors_z[j] * pij;
        }
        pressureGrad_x[idx] *= 0.5;
        pressureGrad_y[idx] *= 0.5;
        pressureGrad_z[idx] *= 0.5;
    }
}

int main(){

    const int num = 1 << 20;
    const int tb = 1024;
    int bg = (num + tb - 1) / tb;

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    //ngb_size
    thrust::device_vector<int> ngb_size(num,27);

    //ngb_offset
    thrust::device_vector<int> ngb_offset(num);
    thrust::exclusive_scan(ngb_size.begin(),ngb_size.end(), ngb_offset.begin());

    //ngh list
    int ngbSize = thrust::reduce(ngb_size.begin(),ngb_size.end());

    std::cout << "ngbSize" << ngbSize << std::endl;

    thrust::device_vector<int> ngb_list(ngbSize);

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){

        int R = (rand()%(num - 0)) + 0;

        ngb_list[i] = R;
    }

    //pressure
    thrust::device_vector<Float> d_pressure(num);
    thrust::sequence(d_pressure.begin(),d_pressure.end(),1);

    //interaction vectors
    thrust::device_vector<Float> d_xInteractionVectors(ngbSize,1);
    thrust::device_vector<Float> d_yInteractionVectors(ngbSize,0);
    thrust::device_vector<Float> d_zInteractionVectors(ngbSize,0);

    //pressure gradients
    thrust::device_vector<Float> pGradx(num);
    thrust::device_vector<Float> pGrady(num);
    thrust::device_vector<Float> pGradz(num);

    //Pressure list
    thrust::device_vector<Float> pressure_list(ngbSize,0);

    cudaEventRecord(start);
    pGrad_calculator<<<bg,tb>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_pressure[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&pressure_list[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_xInteractionVectors[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_yInteractionVectors[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_zInteractionVectors[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&ngb_offset[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&ngb_size[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&ngb_list[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&pGradx[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&pGrady[0]),
                                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&pGradz[0]),
                                num);

    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

    float milliseconds = 0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    std::cout << "KERNEL TIME =  " << milliseconds << "  milliseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the looks of your kernel, it has low computation complexity and lots of global memory loads and stores, which is what you see in the profiling results. In addition, depending on size vector, the kernel may be very divergent.

Comment: I think the one word answer to this question is no - you have a very low ratio of FLOPs to memory transactions, and non-coalesced loads.

Comment: As others noted, you're going to be most heavily influenced by bandwidth in this kernel. You might try adding `const __restrict__` to `interactionVectors` though to see if that helps with read performance. See http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/index.html#read-only-data-cache for more information.

Comment: @talonmies doing the loop Unroll will increase the performance dramatically. Do you have any other comment?

Comment: @jefflarkin Thank you for comment. I tested it and seems it is not effective.

Comment: @talonmies, is shared memory useful for my kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Likely the compiler can not optimize your code properly and many extra loads and writes are used.

Try writing the code like this:

```
__global__ void pGrad_calculator(Float* pressure, Float* pressure_list,
                                 Float* interactionVectors_x, 
                                 Float* interactionVectors_y, 
                                 Float* interactionVectors_z,
                                 int* ngb_offset, int* ngb_size, 
                                 int* ngb_list, Float* pressureGrad_x, 
                                 Float* pressureGrad_y, Float* pressureGrad_z,
                                 int num)
{
    unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < num){
        Float x=pressureGrad_x[idx];
        Float y=pressureGrad_y[idx];
        Float z=pressureGrad_z[idx];
        Float pressure_local=pressure[idx];
        int offset=ngb_offset[idx];
        int end=offset+ngb_size[idx];
        for (int j = offset; j < end; j++){
            Float pij = (pressure_local + pressure[ngb_list[j]]);
            x += interactionVectors_x[j] * pij; 
            y += interactionVectors_y[j] * pij;
            z += interactionVectors_z[j] * pij;
        }
        pressureGrad_x[idx] = 0.5*x;
        pressureGrad_y[idx] = 0.5*y;
        pressureGrad_z[idx] = 0.5*z;
    }
}
```

But even with this optimization, you will most likely get nowhere near peak flops as you will be limited by memory bandwidth. You are doing less than two floating point ops per double/ 8 bytes. That gives you upper bound on peak flops of 288 GB/s * 2 FOps / 8 bytes = 72 GFlop/s or about 5% peak.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I applied the changes and tested. The performance is a bit better (3% - 5%)

Comment: Is it now running at 3-5% of peak performance? That would be a huge improvement over the 0.2% performance you were stating earlier? (>15x speedup)  Or is it 3-5% faster? (0.2% -> 0.21%) If it is running at 3-5% peak now, that is all you can expect from that GPU because the kernel is limited by memory bandwidth.

Comment: I mean just after applying your comment, the performance improved between 3% to 5% comparing to 0.2%. I also applied unrolling loops technique and it was very very effective.